# Why do I receive ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED after pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

For Android, I've written some code with a service that upon execution, the service looks for my BT device and calls device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord for paired devices that it finds (right now, only one). This works great.

For testing purposes, while the service is running, I, manually, unpair and then pair it again. When I do this, I get the pairing and connect, but then I receive ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.

In short, it looks like this:

When I pair, I get the following:

```
I/MainService﹕ Entering Service bcrcvrBluetooth bcReceiver: Action = android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
I/MainService﹕ Service bcrcvrBluetooth: action = BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED
I/MainService﹕ Prev State: BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE
I/MainService﹕ New State: BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING
```

Then it is time to enter the pin. Afterwards, I see the following:

```
I/MainService﹕ Entering Service bcrcvrBluetooth bcReceiver: Action = android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED
I/MainService﹕ Service bcrcvrBluetooth: action = BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED

I/BTDevice﹕ Creating socket
I/BTDevice﹕ Device socket created

I/MainService﹕ Entering Service bcrcvrBluetooth bcReceiver: Action = android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
I/MainService﹕ Service bcrcvrBluetooth: action = BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED
I/MainService﹕ Prev State: BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING
I/MainService﹕ New State: BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED
I/MainService﹕ Device Paired.

I/MainService﹕ Entering Service bcrcvrBluetooth bcReceiver: Action = android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
I/MainService﹕ Service bcrcvrBluetooth: action = BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
```

Ideally, I would include some code to help; however, it is spread out across multiple classes, threads, and etc... The short version is that everything looks great until I receive the ACL_DISCONNECTED for some unknown reason. This throws my code into handling a case where a device that has been removed. If I could narrow my search, I'll gladly post some code.

Why would I receive ACL_DISCONNECTED after pairing?

EDIT:

For anyone else who might make the same stupid mistake I did. It turns out that I was attempting to create the BT socket before I received ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED with BOND_BONDED. This seems to have caused an ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED. I would have expected an error in this case, but I guess not. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Just one more comment. What you are describing is valid not only for RFCOMM, but also for A2DP. Take care that the method createBond() NOT ALWAYS make the bond and profile connection (it depends on the hardware, I have tested with different)

So, the correct way to do that is to call createBond(), wait for BOND_BONDED event, and then make a connection to the A2DP proxy. After the A2DP_CONNECTED event, the conction is reliable